# Why am I getting an 'Expression Result Unused' warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, expression

I have a piece of code that is giving me a 'Expression Result Unused' warning. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

```
  if(task.typeForThis.typeID == @"DivisionAT"){

    probsPerDayLabel.hidden = NO;
    whatToDoLabel.hidden = YES;
    //int ppdi = task.probsPerDay;
    //NSString *ppd = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", ppdi];
    probsPerDayLabel.text = @"Do %i problems today.",task.probsPerDay; //Right here

}
```

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
probsPerDayLabel.text = @"Do %i problems today.",task.probsPerDay
```

should be:

```
probsPerDayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do %i problems today.",task.probsPerDay];
```

In your version, the result of task.probsPerDay is completely unused, and the text on the label will be "Do %i problems today.", without the `%i` being replaced by a number.

Comment: @Joe: That can't be true. You'd get an integer converted to a pointer error. I've tried it in Xcode and it isn't.

Comment: @Joe: No, it's equivalent to `(probsPerDayLabel.text = @"Do %i problems today."), task.probsPerDay;`. The comma has lower precedence than assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using the `stringWithFormat:` method of `NSString`, like this:

```
probsPerDayLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do %i problems today.", task.probsPerDay];
```